# Button inside jQuery Datatables which calls PHP script?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I implemented a table using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/).

[image: Table]

This is the code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
    var table = $('#tbl_user').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data_user.php",
        "bPaginate":true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "pageLength": 10,
        "columns": [
            { mData: 'name' } ,
            { mData: 'address' },
            { mData: 'city' },
            { mData: 'postalcode' },
            { mData: 'email' },
            { mData: 'supervisor' },
            {
                mData: null,       
                "bSortable": false,
               "mRender": function(data, type, full) {
                return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=update.php?' + 'name=foo' + '>' + 'Edit' + '</a>'; }
            }

        ],
        "dom": 'Bfrtip',
        "buttons": [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    }); 

});
```

There's one issue, though. Let's say I'm going to click the "Edit" button on user "123". The button is supposed to call a PHP script update.php, with "123" as it's parameter. How to do that? I tried:

```
return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=update.php?' + 'name='+mData:name + '>' + 'Edit' + '</a>'; }
```

Well it doesn't work.

Comment: `mData:name` doesn't seem like valid syntax in that context.  You have a `data` variable available in that function, what's in that variable?

Comment: Yup, `mData:name` is surely throwing an error in the console. You likely want `mData.name`

Comment: @DelightedD0D mdata.name doesn't work. probably because it's declared as null in the block?

Comment: That depends entirely on where you are trying to call that code. you only show your `return` line. What comes before that? How is `mData` defined in that context? You need to show more of that code.

Comment: Actually, the button part is not mine. I'm not really well versed in JS, so I try Googling looking for some quick solution. Too bad it doesn't end up well. I'm open for suggestions, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close to what you want to achieve.

Mind you, there are two ways

1. Via Ajax
2. Use javascript to open a new page `update.php` with the param.

It all depends on which one is applicable, the two options follow the same principle.
But, in this example, am gonna stick with option 2. Let me know if you want option 1 too.

Update this section as shown:

```
return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="'+callScript(123)+'">' + 'Edit' + '</a>'; }
```

Then add a function to handle this onclick event

```
 function callScript(id){

   var  url ="update.php?id="+id;
    window.open(url,"_self")

    }
```

Comment: On my case, I want to retrieve the name. How to do that?